# RegExp - catching all words ending with colon

Tags: regex

I have an `almost-json` file. Est. 1000 lines. Here is some part of it:

```
level: {
            1: {
                cost: 200,
                hp: 300,
                townhall: { required: 2, max: 0  }
            },
            2: {
                cost: 1000,
                hp: 500,
                townhall: { required: 2, max: 25  }
            },
        }
```

All code is almost like this. Hundreds of nested objects. I want to add `double quotes` to all `keys` *(just string ones)* in this file. This means all strings ending with colons. Like this:

```
"level": {
                1: {
                    "cost": 200,
                    "hp": 300,
                    "townhall": { "required": 2, "max": 0  }
                },
                2: {
                    "cost": 1000,
                    "hp": 500,
                    "townhall": { "required": 2, "max": 25  }
                },
            }
```

I saw some similar questions but they were not what i am looking for.

Comment: What language or tool are you using?  Also, this is a little bit nitpicky but you do not currently have a json file, because if it was json all of the keys would already have quotes.

Comment: you are right. forget to specify it. updated question. thank you. @F.J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing all matches of

```
/([a-z\d_-]+):/gi
```

With

```
"\1":
```

Comment: Is this targetting javascript?

Comment: @Gusdor is just a PCRE. it is not "targeting" anything particular.

Comment: @BradAllred Hate to be a pedant (you started it), but we could say it's targeting any PCRE compatible interpreter?

Comment: @Gusdor yes, that sounds like a fair statement. it is independent of programming language, but dependent on a PCRE implementation which is common in many languages (yes javascript included).

Comment: this works. replacement part should be "$1": . and can we not take integers? only words?

Comment: found it:  ([a-z\-]+):

Comment: @AliOguzhanYildiz this will not include keys like "hell0world", which is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Florian Peschka's answer but without language sensitive switches:

```
([a-zA-Z\d])+:
```

replacement string:

```
"$1":
```

or:

```
"\1":
```

...whichever works.

Comment: i cant call replace or test functions to test your code with javascript. probably my code is an object. what do you suggest?

Comment: @AliOguzhanYildiz I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have a file which you want to modify?